# Merge two json payload with dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a Mule flow that calls two REST API's resulting in two json list payloads. I need to obtain a merged json list from these two payloads.

I managed to achieve this with a scatter-gather flow with a custom aggregator strategy. However the code I had to write for this looks rather messy and it's slow.

Is there any way to achieve this using dataweave?`

input Json list 1:

`[{
    "ID": "1",
    "firstName": "JANE""familyName": "DOE",
    "Entities": [{
        "ID": "515785",
        "name": "UNKOWN UNITED",
        "callSign": "UU"
    }]
},
{
    "ID": "2",
    "firstName": "JOHN",
    "familyName": "DOE",
    "Entities": [{
        "Entities_ID": "515785",
        "name": "UNKOWN UNITED",
        "callSign": "UU"
    }]
}]`

input Json list 2:

`[{
    "ID": "1",
    "firstName": "JANE",
    "familyName": "DOE",
    "Entities": [{
        "Entities_ID": "8916514",
        "name": "UNKOWN INCORPORATED",
        "callSign": "UI"
    }]
},
{
    "ID": "4",
    "firstName": "JAKE",
    "familyName": "DOE",
    "Entities": [{
        "Entities_ID": "8916514",
        "name": "UNKOWN INCORPORATED",
        "callSign": "UI"
    }]
}]`

desired output is a merged list without duplicate IDs:

`[{
    "ID": "1",
    "firstName": "JANE",
    "familyName": "DOE",
    "Entities": [{
        "Entities_ID": "515785",
        "name": "UNKOWN UNITED",
        "callSign": "UU"
    },
    {
        "Entities_ID": "8916514",
        "name": "UNKOWN INCORPORATED",
        "callSign": "UI"
    }]
},
{
    "ID": "2",
    "firstName": "JOHN",
    "familyName": "DOE",
    "Entities": [{
        "Entities_ID": "515785",
        "name": "UNKOWN UNITED",
        "callSign": "UU"
    }]
},
{
    "ID": "4",
    "firstName": "JAKE",
    "familyName": "DOE",
    "Entities": [{
        "Entities_ID": "8916514",
        "name": "UNKOWN INCORPORATED",
        "callSign": "UI"
    }]
}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with dataweave where payload is list1 and flowVars.list2 is list2

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var mergeddata = flowVars.list2 groupBy $.ID
---
payload map ((data,index) -> {
   ID: data.ID,
   firstName : data.firstName,
   familyName : data.familyName,
   Entities : data.Entities ++ (mergeddata[data.ID].Entities default [])
}) ++   
(flowVars.list2 filter (not (payload.ID contains $.ID)))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's a good start, however the resultset needs to have merged entities where there are duplicate ID's in the two lists. Like this:

`[{
 "ID": "1",
 "firstName": "JANE",
 "familyName": "DOE",
 "Entities": [{
  "Entities_ID": "515785",
  "name": "UNKOWN UNITED",
  "callSign": "UU"
 },
 {
  "Entities_ID": "8916514",
  "name": "UNKOWN INCORPORATED",
  "callSign": "UI"
 }]
}]`

Comment: I have updated the answer found issue in last answer.

Comment: That seems to be doing just the trick, thank you very much for your help!