# How to create a json message from 2 different json message using Dataweave

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I want to create a json message from 2 different Json message. Both input messages are coming from flow variables. How can it be done using Dataweave.

Message 1:

```
    [

     {
         "userId": 11,
         "name": "ABC",
         "age": 30
     },

     {
         "userId": 44,
         "name": "XYZ",
         "age": 30
     }

     ]
```

**Message 2:**

```
 [

 {
     "userId": 11,
     "Address": "BLR"
 },
 {
     "userId": 44,
     "Address": "CCU"
 }

 ]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[

 {
     "userId": 11,
     "name": "ABC",
     "Address": "BLR"
 },
 {
     "userId": 44,
     "name": "XYZ",
     "Address": "CCU"
 }

 ]
```

Thank You in advance,
Nitesh

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookup instead of filter as using filter is performance overhead.
Try this

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
 %var adressLookup = {(  flowVars.data map  {
    ($.userId ++ "") : $
 })}
 ---
payload map {
    userId : $.userId,
    name : $.name,
    Address : adressLookup[$.userId ++ ""].Address
}
```

where payload is message1 and flowVars.data is message2

P.S : I have used `$.userId ++ ""` as key in string format for hashmap, some how numeric key isn't work with  weave hashmap.

also refer [Merge two json payload with dataweave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723094/merge-two-json-payload-with-dataweave/39724118#39724118)

Hope this helps.